# How do I tell an application (Brave in this case) to remember that I've allowed it access to Kdewallet?

Tags: kwallet

I've found many articles with instructions for disabling the wallet altogether, but I'd like to use it, just not have to authenticate every time I open Brave. Is there a way to grant permanent permissions for an application to access Kdewallet?

Here are some links to similar questions where the only answers are to disable it:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205161/annoying-kde-wallet-service-popup-the-application-kded5-has-requested-to-open

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109179/kde-wallet-keychain

I'd really like to be able to save encrypted passwords locally without needing to give permissions every time.

Thank you

Comment: It is not an application that is remembering. This would not be secure.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by that? Also, if it's a computer used only by me, should I not have the option of sidestepping this security?

Comment: It will be the wallet that gives access. Like with doors, it is the door that decides if you are allowed in. We don't get each person to decide. "hay you criminals, you have to decide that you can't come in." Therefore the configuration will be with the wallet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not with Brave. The problem is that `kwallet` is not already open and waiting.

This is for openSUSE. Other distros may name their files a little differently, but this should get you on the right track. If you open `yast` and search the packages for the word `wallet`, you can find the few that contain `kwallet` and are not installed by default. You need the modules that connect `kwallet` to the desktop manager. This will allow your initial KDE login to open your `kwallet`. Now, other programs don't have to ask you to open it.

To install them at the command line, the files names are

```
pam_kwallet
pam_kwallet-32bit
pam_kwallet-common
signon-kwallet-extension
```

After much searching and finding no answer to this question, I figured it out on my own. I felt I needed to share it for others. I don't understand why these were not part of my default install, but mine was very minimalistic.